# Command not found, c++ application

Tags: c++, linux

I'm workin in a bingo application, in pairs, my partner sends me his source code, it compiled  with no problems but when I tried to run it:

```
~/Escritorio/Bingo $ g++ -o Bingo main.cpp Bingo.cpp Bingo.h -std=c++11

~/Escritorio/Bingo $ ./Bingo --version

$: Command not found
```

it saids no command found /(orden no encontrada)

He's on windows while I'm on linux instead, I never had this problem before.

Comment: show how you compiled and linked...

Comment: doesn't look like a c++ problem. `./bingo` tries to open a program called "bingo" in the current directory, so make sure that you got the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compilation command builds a `Bingo` executable. Your execution command tries to run a `bingo` program. Case is significant.

You really should compile with all warnings and debug info and don't need to pass any header file to the compiler (header which you should `#include` inside `Bingo.cpp` and `main.cpp`):

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -g  main.cpp Bingo.cpp -o Bingo
```

Then, edit your code till you got no warnings, and repeat the compilation above.

Check with

```
ls -l Bingo Bingo.cpp main.cpp
```

that you've got that executable and that its timestamp is newer than the source code.

Then try to run it:

```
./Bingo --version
```

if you need to debug it, use `gdb`  as

```
gdb ./Bingo
```

Comment: Sorry i just typed wrong, in fact I'm trying with Bingo in both commads

Comment: don't know why but I just compile it with your suggestion, no warnings as result, then I tried ./Bingo --version, and now it woks, than you very much